# Opening file with Process.Start starts process but does not open window

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, ms-word

I am trying to open a document with `Process.Start` in an ASP.NET web application. In this case, I am opening a Word file `(.docx)`, but will be opening any type of file in the future.

My understanding of `Process.Start` is that the application is determined from the extension of the file path passed as a parameter, and opened.

The code I am using is very simple:

```
Process.Start("C:\\test.docx");
```

The file exists, and I am not getting any exceptions when the code is run. However, Word is not opening.

I have monitored my running processes through task manager whilst the code is running, and have noticed that a `WINWORD.EXE` process is starting with the User Name of the application pool being used (`DefaultAppPool`) in this case.

Why would the process be starting, but no Word window opening?

Edit: In case there is a better solution, here is my situation:

I am allowing users to upload documents, which are saved in an Oracle database as a `BLOB`. The user is then able to view their saved documents, and open them. What is the best way to extract a byte array from a `BLOB`, and open it using the correct application?

Comment: The process exists within the context of IIS which is why you don't see a window. You really shouldn't be launching Word from a web server though.

Comment: @DavidG, please see my update in case there may be a better solution.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to launch word server-side using ASP.NET? I is valid to launch external processes on the threadpool, but I don't see how you would open a Graphical UI on the server?

Comment: This is basically an X/Y problem. You want the user to view the document he/she uploaded, you thought using Word would help you, so you ask about Word. Instead you need a component that can show word files (and/or any other file formats you allow the user to upload). Opening Word server-side is not going to accomplish anything. You could try simply downloading the file, which would open the file locally on the client in the associated program. **Opening it server-side is not going to work.**

Comment: I have voted  to close this question - I have obviously misunderstood what I am trying to achieve, and attempting to do it in a way that will never work. Thanks for your comments.